# WPF Using textbox custom style causing not to be able to insert text to the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I wrote a custom style for my `TextBox` controls and now when I'm using it, I cannot type text to my `TextBox` while running.
Here is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="TextBox" >
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="41"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="114"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFDDDDDD"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/App;component/Images/BarsForms/precent_bg.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="None" />    
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You have set Focusable to false... <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>... Thats why you are not able to type anything... Make it true and you will be able to type...

Answer (score 1):

```
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
```

`Focusable` set to false in your style prevents the cursor from selecting the `TextBox` and ability to set the cursor for typing.